# Whether transactions inside a roth/traditional IRA incur a current tax liability

Tags: united-states, ira

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_IRA#Differences_from_a_traditional_IRA) about Roth IRA says about its differences from traditional IRA

> **Transactions inside a Roth IRA** (including capital gains, dividends, and interest) do not incur **a current tax liability**.

What does a current tax liability mean?

Do transactions inside a traditional IRA incur a current tax liability?

Comment: That sentence in Wikipedia is badly misplaced in the "Differences from Traditional IRAs" section since it invites the inference that,_ in contrast to Traditional IRAs_, transactions within a Roth IRA do not incur a current tax liability. Transactions within a Traditional IRA _also_ do not incur a current income tax liability.

Answer (score 3):

Current tax liability means that you'd have to pay taxes on the capital gain, dividend or interest incurred by the transaction. In some cases, there may be a portion withheld to cover the taxes in some cases.

> Do transactions inside a traditional IRA incur a current tax
>   liability?

No, though there is a deferred tax liability as all distributions from a Traditional IRA are taxed as ordinary income.